# JSP - Servlet calling goes wrong

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a problem with my practice project. Maybe I'm blind, but i can not solve the riddle. Hopefully this is not just another duplicate.

1. There is a list inside a jsp to present objects in an abstract way. From that I link each to a servlet with a `<a href>`.

```
       <c:forEach var="object" items="${dealer.objectList}" varStatus="status">
              <div class="changableElement">
                        <jsp:include page="/Object/objectDetails.jsp"></jsp:include>
                        <a href="/MyProjekt/ObjectResolverServlet/${object.id}" id="send">Change</a>
              </div>
       </c:forEach>
```

This works fine.

2. The `ObjectResolverServlet` gets the object again from background and puts it in the request as an attribute.

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws      ServletException, IOException {
       System.out.println("Mark #1");
       String objectId = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
       MyObject obj = dbHandler.getMyObjectById(objectId );
       System.out.println(obj);
       request.setAttribute("objectDetails", obj);
       response.setContentType("text/html");        
       getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/MyObjectChangePage").forward(request, response) ;
}
```

On `MyObjectChangePage` the user is able to manipulate details of `obj`.

3. `MyObjectChangePage` consists mainly of a form, textfields and submit buttons that directs to another servlet.

```
<form id="object_change_values_form" action="ObjectChangeServlet" method="post" >
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label><br> 
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="${obj.name}" />
        <span id="nameDetails"bla bla ..</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="origin"Origin:</label><br>
        <input id="origin" name="origin" type="text" value="${obj.origin}" />
        <span id="originDetails">bla bla ../span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="year">Bitte Jahrgang eingeben!</label><br>
        <input id="year" name="year" type="text" value="${obj.year}" />
        <span id="yearDetails">bla bla ..</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="description">Description</label><br>
        <textarea name='description' id='description'>${obj.description}</textarea>
        <span id="descriptionDetails">bla bla ..</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="priceSelling">Price</label><br>
        <input id="priceSelling" name="priceSelling" type="text" value="${obj.priceSelling}" />
        <span id="priceSellingDetails">bla bla ..</span>
    </div>

    <input id="send" type="submit" value="Change" name = "button"/>                     
    <input id="send" type="submit" value="Cancel" name = "button"/>
</form>
```

4. `ObjectChangeServlet` is never called - instead the output Mark #1 from `ObjectResolverServlet` and in a new line `null` is printed. 
    I found that from 'ObjectResolverServlet' the `doPost` method is called. Guess i made a weired mistake.

Parts of my `web.xml` here:

```
  ....
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ObjectChangeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>impl.servlets.ObjectChangeServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ObjectChangeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ObjectChangeServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ObjectChangePage</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/Object/object_change_values.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ObjectChangePage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ObjectChangePage</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <description>Gets the object by id</description>
    <servlet-name>ObjectResolverServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>impl.servlets.ObjectResolverServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ObjectResolverServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ObjectResolverServlet/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ....
```

Comment: Is the JSP rendering what you think it is? When you look at the request in Firebug/etc. what's the URL being POSTed to? You might just need to make the form `action` attribute absolute.

Comment: @Dave Newton When I check the form element i can see the right action notated `<form id="object_change_values_form" action="MyProjekt/ObjectChangeServlet" method="post" >` It seams that a former request is done twice. :(

Comment: Then something else is wrong--check the POST request itself. We can't see the rest of your code/config, we can't verify what's been deployed is what you think it is, we can't see the servlet you think you're supposed to be POSTing to.

Comment: @Dave Newton Finally I've got it! You where right, it was the 'action' attribute now i changed it again to `<form id="object_change_values_form" action="/MyProjekt/ObjectChangeServlet" method="post" >`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Rather than put your app context in manually, consider using JSTL's url tag. Glad you worked it out.

Comment: @FordPrefect Please put your comment as an answer, so that it would be helpful for others. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution thanks to the good clues in the comments above. It's simply that the action in `<form .. >` tag must point to the processing servlet in a absolute manner, so my first attempt in 3. was absolute wrong

**wrong**
`<form id="object_change_values_form" action="ObjectChangeServlet" method="post" >`

but the **correct** solution is 
`<form id="object_change_values_form" action="/MyProjekt/ObjectChangeServlet" method="post" >`